# how many buffer used by a dataflow in SSIS package?

Tags: ssis

i have two data flows in my SSIS package,when i execute the package.i want to know the two task will use one buffer area(maybe 10M) or they will use two separate buffer area(each one use 5M)

Answer (score 0):

See this article to get some insight on the buffer usage in SSIS.  I would assume that each data flow task will allocate its own buffer (since they may be running concurrently based upon your control flow design), but that those buffers are constrained as discussed in the linked article.

http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/biz/SSIS_An_Inside_View_Part_3_p1.aspx